# React component class, can't write async method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm hazy on async, and I'm not sure why I'm getting a syntax error in my react component while trying to write a simple async method.

```js
class Locations extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.searchProducts = this.searchProducts.bind(this);

  }

    async searchProducts(product_name, storeId) {
    let response =  await axios.get(
      `https://api.goodzer.com/products/v0.1/search_in_store/?storeId=${storeId}&query=${product_name}&apiKey=125cbddf3880cb1ba652a7c269ba1eb0`
    );
    console.log(response);
    return response.data.products;

}

  componentWillMount() {
    let products = [];
    this.props.searchLocations(this.props.navigation.state.params.product_name, this.props.navigation.state.params.searchRadius)
      .then(
          products = (this.props.locations.map(
          location => ({[location.id]: this.searchProducts(
            this.props.navigation.state.params.product_name, location.storeid
          )}))
        )
      );

      console.log(products);
  }

  render() {
    const displayLocations = this.props.locations.map(
      location => (<Text key={location.id}>{location.name}</Text>)
    );
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>HELLO</Text>
        <View>{displayLocations}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm getting a syntax error: 'Unexpected token, expected ('.

I don't understand how this is any different than the examples given here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function

Comment: Are you using babel? Can you share your babel config?

Comment: At which line does error occur? Note, `this.searchProducts()` returns a `Promise` object

Comment: That's the babelrc? 

`{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: The error is on line 32

Comment: Also, I thought using 'await' means that 'response' will not be a promise by the time the function returns?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error is at

```
  .then(
      products = /* missing `>` at arrow function */ (this.props.locations.map(
      location => ({[location.id]: this.searchProducts(
        this.props.navigation.state.params.product_name, location.storeid
      )}))
    )
  )
```

`.then()` expects a function as argument, `this.searchProducts()` returns a `Promise` object, `async` also need to be set within `.map()` callback function

```
async componentWillMount() {
  let products = await this.props
  .searchLocations(
    this.props.navigation.state.params.product_name, 
    this.props.navigation.state.params.searchRadius
  )
  .then(
    () => 
        Promise.all(this.props.locations.map(async(location) =>
          ({[location.id]: await this.searchProducts(
            this.props.navigation.state.params.product_name, 
            location.storeid
          )}))
        )
  );
  console.log(products);
}
```

Comment: I replace my .then() with your revision but I still get `Syntax error: await is a reserved word`

Comment: @killer_manatee See updated post. `async` needs to be set at the function where `await` is used, that is, at `.map()` callback

Comment: Ok, the syntax error is gone. Do you know how I would actually get the result of the Promise.all and store it in the array? What I want is an array of objects with location.id as the key and the result of searchProducts as the value. Thanks

Comment: `products` is the array. Have not tried reactjs, not sure if `products` should be returned from `ComponentWillMount`?

Comment: I'm confused about how to access the data that the promise eventually returns. Shouldn't the promise eventually return an array of objects? I've done some reading about promises but I don't understand how to 'get' them when they resolve

Comment: The `products` variable is the array of objects. What does `console.log(products)` within `ComponentWillMount` log?

Comment: When I console.log `products` I get `Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}`

Comment: @killer_manatee `products` should be an array of objects, yes? Is `{ "_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null, }` an object within the array?

Comment: No, that's some kind of garbage data. products should be an array of objects like {id: 'xyz123, 'name: 'coffee maker', price: '19.99'} etc

Comment: What do you mean by "garbage data"? What does `locations` array contain?

Answer (score 0):

Your `componentDidMount` function is syntactically invalid. You have not supplied a proper function to the `then` call.  Also, your `console.log` should be inside the then call.